# Mousseline sauce, use the white or the yolk of the egg?

Tags: eggs, sauce, cream

I always used the yolk of the egg for preparing mousseline sauce, but sometimes I see recipes on the web where they use the white of the egg.

Like in the definition on this site [epicurious](http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry/?id=3574)

> mousseline
>   [moos-LEEN]
>   1. Any sauce to which whipped cream or beaten egg whites have been added just prior to serving to give it a light, airy consistency.

So what's the 'orthodox' way of making mousseline sauce?

And what difference would it make to use the whites instead of the yolks?

I guess, I will have to try it one of these days, but was wondering about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ***should**** be made (classically) with egg whites.  It is supposed to be a light hollandaise based sauce.  Obviously the white is lighter. All the fat from in the mousseline should come from the butter, not yolk.

Comment: I find this answer confusing. If it is a hollandaise, how can it be made without yolk? Where do the emulsifiers come from? Could you maybe explain a bit more how it is made?

Comment: Apologies. Start by making a hollandaise.  A mousseline is a hollandaise based sauce (just like a bearnaise).  It is what happens after that makes it into a mousseline.  Use whites, not yolks. That's all I meant. Hope this clears up any confusion.